# Is my code type safe?

Tags: java, type-safety

I am pretty sure this is type safe, but just wanted to check as Eclipse is asking me to put a `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation.

```
Map<String, IFace> faces;

public <T extends IFace> T getFace(String key)
{
    return (T) faces.get(key);
}
```

Comment: Answering my own question: No it's not because I can have a two DIFFERENT classes `ClassA` & `ClassB` that both implement `IFace` in `faces`. At runtime `T` could be `ClassA` or `ClassB`.

Comment: Starred as I'm very interested in a similar problem

Comment: Why have the generics here? If you're just referencing things as `IFace`, then you don't need the generics/casting

Comment: Why don't you simply have `Map<String, T> faces`?

Comment: Note that it isn't Eclipse who is calling the shots: it is the JLS, which precisely defines what code will produce a "this needs an unchecked cast" warning. The Java Generics specification states that your code is type-safe only as long as it doesn't generate any such warnings.

Answer (score 4):

It is not type safe. You are upcasting here so if you cast to an incompatible derived class you will come across an error at some point.

For example if `A_Face` and `B_Face` both extend `IFace`. You might at some point be casting a  `B_Face` as an `A_Face` which is not type safe.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the extreme case. Lets say `IFace` is acutally `Object`, your code then looks like this:

```
static Map<String, Object> myMap = new HashMap<>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    myMap.put("ONE", 1);
    myMap.put("TWO", "TWO");
    myMap.put("THREE", new Date());

    final Calendar calendar1 = getThing("ONE");
    final Calendar calendar2 = getThing("TWO");
    final Calendar calendar3 = getThing("THREE");
}

public static <T> T getThing(String key) {
    return (T) myMap.get(key);
}
```

So you are putting at `class` than `extends Object` into your `Map` (so any `class`).

But, when you call `getThing` you are doing an implicit cast to your desired type. It should be fairly obvious that I can call `getThing` with any `class` also and it will blindly attempt to cast to it.

In the above example I am putting some things into my `Map` and then attempting to retrieve them all as `Calendar`s.

Answer (score 0):

A classic way to handle this is with a "typesafe heterogeneous container":

```
Map<Class<?>, IFace> faces;

public <T extends IFace> T getFace(Class<T> key) {
    return t.cast(faces.get(key));
}
```

You use the class of the interface as a key, rather than a string, and then you can use the class passed as a key to safely cast the return value to the right type.